# Access Windows Phone from Remote Desktop Computer

Tags: windows-phone-8, remote-access

Can we control Windows Phone 8 from a desktop system or does WP8 SDK has any API which support such accessibility?

Comment: What do you mean by access? If you want to control the phone remotely then the answer is no.

Comment: Yes I mean control only. Thanks @IvanCrojachKaračić